# When to call Composite.changed() in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

After reading [`Composite#changed(Control[])`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html#changed%28org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control%5B%5D%29) I have a hard time understanding when I need to call `changed()`. In case of a GUI build from several layers of composites with associated layouts, do I need to call it on all parent composite with layouts which the changing control is part of?

Comment: I've written a lot of UI with SWT and I didn't even know this method existed until I read this question.  Is there a problem you're running into with your layouts that you think `#changed()` will help you with?  Or are you trying to ensure the completeness of your application?

Comment: No problems, just trying to understand.